# Native (C#) Client using "Office365 API" unable to create Mail Folder in Online account

Tags: office365

I am using the new Office365 API (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7e947621-ef93-4de7-93d3-d796c43ba34f)
 to have a C# client connect to Office365 online, in particular the Exchange Service. 
The client is able to read and send mails on account of an authorized Office365 User.
The client application fails to create a new (sub-) folder either in the root online exchange directory or in any sub-folder, although the owner has set the parent folder rights accordingly (manual input in https: //outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=SomeCompany.onmicrosoft.com).

My source code:

```
Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.ExchangeClient XClient;

 //authorization, XClient can read/send mails....
IFolder newFolder = new Microsoft.Office365.Exchange.Folder();
newFolder.DisplayName = "someFolderName";
newFolder.ParentFolderId = "Some valid parent folder Id";
newFolder.ClassName = "IPF.Note";
newFolder.Id = "AAMkAGVlNT....";  
await XClient.Me.Folders.AddFolderAsync(newFolder); 
                      //throws exception "ID must be non-empty"
```

From available information how to "create a folder by using EWS" 
(see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535504(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_createfolderews)
I would expect that only Parent ID and Display Name need to be set.
I even provided a non-empty ID  although it does not seem sensible in view of the available information about EWS.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I figured out the answer myself. Instead of

```
 await XClient.Me.Folders.AddFolderAsync(newFolder);
```

one needs to traverse the folder tree to get the (possibly empty) ChildFolders Collection of the  parent folder. E.g., via

```
 await XClient.Me.Folders.GetById(parentId).ChildFolders.AddFolderAsync(newFolder);
```

Furthermore, setting the parentFolderID field of the newFolder does not matter.

Regards,
Martin

PS: The original attempt was in line with the procedure to create new One Drive Sub-folders via:

```
  Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint.SharePointClient SpClient;
  ...
  await SpClient.Files.AddFolderAsync(folder);
```